# WPF application (not browser) and navigation

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to develop a desktop application based on WPF. How do I navigate via C# code from one page to another or from one page in a window?

Comment: Have you had a look into the [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) article? It also explains how to use navigation in standalone applications.

Comment: i saw it... but it explain only for browser application...

Comment: Then you haven't read to the end. See [this section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#The_NavigationWindow_Class) about the NavigationWindow class.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. And from a mainwindow to a page?

Comment: Oh thanks. And i if i want to navigate from a window to a page?

Comment: Desktop applications typically don't follow the "page-and-navigation" paradigm you might think of for a browser app (or website). Instead, there are windows. How you organize windows and their content will depend on the user experience you want to construct. However, there is this thing called a UWP application which does support something like pages and page navigation - you might want to read up on that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at the following links below - these will give you a better understanding of navigating through a WPF application providing examples and sample apps.

[How to Build, Manage and Navigate the User Interface of a WPF Application](https://web.archive.org/web/20130310050236/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Build-Manage-and-fdd0074a)

[Simple Navigation](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation)

[More advanced Navigation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee)

A really easy way to navigate through an application I find is that if you add a `Frame` within a `Window` and then for your other corresponding pages, use `Page` and you need to do in the code behind of your window is as follows:

```
FrameContent.Navigate(new ExampleView());
```

Comment: And if i want to navigate from a Windows to a page?

Comment: @user1593416 You would have a `Frame` within a `Window` to help do that (mentioned in my answer). The same code above works when using a `Frame` to navigate from a `Window` to a `Page`. Take a look at the second link that I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple example of navigation by using [Data Templates and ContentControl](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/)