# How to navigate to previous page in WPF but keep the data?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I navigate to the previous page in WPF but keep the data?

Suppose I have 2 pages in my app `Page1` and `Page2`. and let's say that in page 1 the user writes some inputs for example his name, email etc...

After the user filled in his details on page 1 he navigated to page 2.

Now he wants to go back to the same page 1, how can he go back to the same page 1 with all his data?

Until now I navigated between pages by creating a new page like this:

```
    private void PreviousButton(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page1 p1 = new Page1();
        NavigationService.Navigate(p1);
    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the previous page. Try to keep a reference to the page instead. If you post a little bit more of your logic specially the part where you navigate to this one, then we can help you

Comment: Look at MVVM pattern. You can keep data in your view model.

Comment: In MVVM, normally the view model is disposed together with its associated view, so the right place for data storage/retrival is the UI independent model/business logic of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a reference of Page1 in Page2:

**Page1: Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxbName" Margin="10"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxbEmail" Margin="10"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnNext" Content="Next Page" Click="BtnNext_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Page1 C#**

```
public partial class Page1 
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var page2 = new Page2(this);
        NavigationService.Navigate(page2);
    }
}
```

**Page2 Xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="LblName" Margin="10"/>
        <Label x:Name="LblEmail" Margin="10"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnPrevious" Content="Previous Page" Click="BtnPrevious_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>    
</Grid>
```

**Page2 C#:**

```
public partial class Page2
{
    private Page1 _page1;

    public Page2(Page1 page1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _page1 = page1;
    }

    private void BtnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(_page1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to implement single Page navigation? Just like Google search in browser, search A -> search B -> goback -> (back to search A page and the search box is A)

Comment: @CodingNinja: There are multiple examples out there. Just by searching WPF navigation you get so many examples. Here a general overview of navigation in WPF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 , and here another question with navigation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15158456/2289942

Comment: thanks, I read more than a lot of answers, maybe I'm going too much for mvvm and it's a bit difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set KeepLive = true in page attribute. Check whether it works for you.