# Load WPF UserControl with user input

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am still new to WPF so excuse this simple question.

But I just don't know how to load a UserControl in WPF where the user entered data.

The following scenario:

User enters data into the view and clicks Next. If he now clicks the Back button on the view, how can I display the entered data again?

Comment: [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15156625/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

As the fastest option is using property "Visibility" with onPropertyChaged.
You can create property

```
    private Visibility m_controlUserVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Visibility ControlUserVisibility
        {
            get { return m_controlUserVisibility; }
            set
            {
                m_controlUserVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

and Binding in XAML

```
<UserControl Visibility="{Binding ControlUserVisibility}"></UserControl>
```

When you want show UserControl - write:

```
ControlUserVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying.
But I'm looking for a way to recover entered data.

Comment: "fastest" doesn't mean proper or acceptable. using `Visibility` type in view models is a violation of MVVM. also hidden controls can be made visible via tools like Snoop. the correct approach will involve somthing like *replacing* controls by changing templates or similar

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your requirement is some form of multi-page wizard control ...

1. Create a set ViewModel classes, one for each page of the wizard, and set an instance of each as properties of your main ViewModel. Add a SelectedPage property and set to the initial page ViewModel. The forward / backward navigation between pages should update the SelectedPage value as appropriate. The entered data will stay in memory and will remain available as the user navigates between pages.
2. In the View, add a ContentControl and bind its Content property to SelectedPage, along with buttons to control the navigation between pages. Create a DataTemplate for each page ViewModel type in the ContentControl's resources, to define the UI layout for that page.

Comment: I worked according to your instructions. 
But the SelectedPage property does not exist with me ?! 
On the internet I find the SelectedPage property only under DevExpress

Comment: you have to create your own SelectedPage property within your MainViewModel class